# Как изменить color элемента в css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Допустим у меня есть такой код, как сделать градиент элемента в CSS именно color(border и background не подходит)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Part1.module.scss';
import {CiMedicalCross} from 'react-icons/ci'
export default function Part1() {
  return (
            <div>
            <CiMedicalCross  className={styles.plus}/>
            </div>
  );
}

.plus{}
```

Comment: ```text gradient```?

Comment: @soledar10 нет, для текста работает , а для таких элементов нет

Comment: использовать ```svg``` ?

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо, попробую загрузить через svg

Comment: Попробуйте написать алгоритм создания градиента - https://dev.to/ndesmic/linear-color-gradients-from-scratch-1a0e

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если учеть, что `color` как CSS-свойство может относиться ТОЛЬКО к тексту, то к тексту его и надо применять (и элемент должен содержать текст, чтобы вы увидели результат):

```css
CiMedicalCross {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, red, gold, cyan, magenta, blue);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <CiMedicalCross  className={styles.plus}>text</CiMedicalCross>
</div>
```

Если же речь о цвете именно элемента, то он может быть только фоновый, т.е., background (border-color не в счет), применяйте градент к фону.

Не очнь понятно из вопроса, почему такая зацикленность именно на свойстве `color` - скрипт рубит все остальное? Заратустра запретил? =)

Comment: Зацикленности нет, просто свойства background не работают(или же я не правильно применял)) ,она закрашивают либо background, либо не работают

Comment: еще раз повторяю: в CSS `color` - к тексту, `border-color` - к рамке, `background` - к фону. В приведенном мной примере градиент применяется к фону и фон просто обрезается по тексту как по маске (сам текст при этом прозрачный).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое

Comment: ваш метод не подходит

Comment: Метод работает. Если он не подходит конкретно в вашей ситуации, то объясните, что именно и как именно вы пытаетесь сделать.